# Navigation Bar Title Image Problem

Tags: iphone, uiimageview, uinavigationbar

I put the image to navigation bar title with the code below, but the image can't fill the all title view. There remains few pixels in right and left sides.

I want to display my image in whole title view area.

Resizing the image doesn't work.

Any ideas?

[self.navController.navigationBar.topItem setTitleView:imageView];

Comment: i'm having kinda the same issue did you find anything useful maybe?

Answer (score 1):

If you need to fill the entire area of the nav bar you can create a category for UINavigationBar and override either drawRect: or drawLayer:inContext: methods. I had some occasional bugs with overriding drawRect though, so I would suggest going with drawLayer:inContext:.

Answer (score 0):

Try by setting imageview as the subview of the title view.